# AWS Cognito + API Gateway + VPC Link: How to extract cognito username?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm currently using aws cognito authenticator in my api gateway integrated to my application via vpc link. I need to extract the cognito username but am not sure how to do so. Is there a way to extract in api gateway? I am not using lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract user data by decode the JWT token, which sent in the request header.

Refer to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/